# I have tried this regex expression: (0\9)[0-9]{8\9} which doesn't meet the validation requirement that I want

Tags: php, html, regex, laravel

I have tried the regex expression of the following condition for both HTML form validation as well as server side validation in Laravel but the expression that I have tried (i.e (0\9)[0-9]{8\9}) couldn't meet the requirement for the validation:
The number should start with either 0 or 9 and the number should be exactly 9 or 10 digits.

Note: The number should be in the form like 9849384748 (beginning with 9 and exactly of 10 digits) or 016563434(beginning with 0 and exactly of 9 digits).

Comment: Can you add to your question what you have tried?

Comment: regex:/^[09][0-9]{8,9}$/' This works for the server side validation. But I need similar pattern for the HTML form validation as well. I tried this: pattern="^[09][0-9]{8,9}+$" for the HTML form validation but it doesn't work. What correction do I need?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ will help, but if your question is about parsing HTML you need to say that in the question! [edit] the question and tell us exactly what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I got the issue solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regular expression:

```
^(0\d{8}|9\d{9})$
```

**Description:**

- `^` asserts position at start of line while `$` at end of line.
- `\d` matches a digit.
- `{8}` and `{9}` matches eight and nine times respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much. It meets my required validation criteria.

Comment: @DixonCh You are welcome. Consider marking the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: I just did. Thank you.